# Files in Nautilus stopped updating automatically, how to fix this?

Tags: nautilus

Files in Nautilus stopped updating automatically. To see a new files I have to refresh a directory (ctrl+R). How to fix this?

Comment: Is that happen all time?

Comment: it started recently, maybe  after a computer freezes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fix by editing `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`.

The file include only a number, i changed it to a larger number with the following command in Ubuntu:

```
echo 1000000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```