# Files on Desktop not updating

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I noticed that when I would, for example, download a file to my Desktop, it would not be reflected visually. That is, I did not see any icon for the file.

Curious, I checked in terminal (ls) and the file was there.

I had managed to solve this by killing nautilus (killall nautilus) then restarting it (nautilus &).

So I'm wondering: why did Nautilus no longer update? Is this a known bug? Is there a config file I need to tweak?

Comment: Does the answer given in http://askubuntu.com/questions/184760/ work for you?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate this error. After I restarted Nautilus, it's been updating for new files. However, it is possible that it could come up later, but how I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the default behavior. Unless you have changed some preferences, nautilus should update the desktop. Maybe nautilus wasn't running, for example it crashed?

Next time the same happens, check whether nautilus is running using pgrep nautilus.

Also, no need to kill it in such a brutal manner, just type `nautilus -q`.

Comment: If Nautilus would have crashed, I wouldn't be able to see anything on my Desktop. At least, when I had killed it, I couldn't see file contents of my Desktop anymore.

Comment: ops, yes, you are right. A bug then, submit it to launchpad.